# How to enable editable combobox open with a value that doesn't exist in its items list?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a WPF editable combobox in a dialog.
This combobox has items from a specific list but can accept also other strings.

The bug I have, though, is that when the user types a string that doesn't exist in the items list and saves it, it all looks fine, and the new string should be saved as the chosen value..

BUT - When the dialog is reopened, the combobox's value is EMPTY.

Any idea why?

This is the combobox's code:

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectedItem="{Binding VariableValue}" ItemsSource="{Binding VariablesValues}" Width="160" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsEnabled="true" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Additional Info:
I think that the issue here is related to the binding of SelectedItem.. Because a free-text typed in the editable textbox doesn't exist in the items list...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: @ozioma Thanks for your comment - rephrased. Let me know if you can help :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say the user types and saves the value? You need to catch that value and add it to VariablesValues for it to be added to the list.

Comment: Thank you. Solved. See below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that in editable chooser works with binding, we should define the value using "Text" property and not "SelectedItem". It works like a charm:

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding VariableValue}" ItemsSource="{Binding VariablesValues}" Width="160" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsEnabled="true" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"/>
```